# jMockit: @Mocked mock object is not initialized in a non-test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I need to mock a logger class on which the classes under test call a static method to obtain an object. Because of this I created a fake implementation of that static function as described in the official tutorial. My fake class looks like this

```
public class FakeLogger extends MockUp<Logger> {
  @Mocked Logger logger;
  @Mock 
  public Logger getLogger() {
      return logger;
  }
}
```

It is used in the test class:

```
public class MyTest {   
    @Mocked Logger logger;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        new FakeLogger();
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Expectations() {{
            logger.warn("message");
            times = 1;
        }};
    /*here classes under test are executed which obtain use the logger by Logger.getLogger().log("message");*/}
```

This implementation does **not work**.
The problem is that Logger.getLogger() returns null because in the fake implementation the object @Mocked Logger logger; seems to be never initialized.

Then I tried the following changes:

```
public class FakeLogger extends MockUp<Logger> {
    @Mocked Logger logger;
    public FakeLogger(Logger l) {
        logger=l;
    }
    @Mock 
    public Logger getRootLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}
```

With the test class initializing the fake implementation:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Mocked Logger logger;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        new FakeLogger(logger);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {        
        new Expectations() {{
            logger.warn("message");
            times = 1;
        }};
    ...}
```

When initializing the fake implementation class with the @Mocked Logger logger; object from the test class it works without a null pointer exception from an uninitialized logger object.

My conclusion would be that @Mocked Logger logger; is only initialized automatically inside the test class but not in the fake class. But according to the official tutorial @Mocked object should always be initialized automatically.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

When JMockit runs, variables annotated with @Tested or @Mocked should be non-null.  Effectively, JMockit is creating a MockImpl for each of them.  Ignoring a lot of the complexity of your post, I focused mostly on the fact your @Mocked logger is null, which makes me strongly suspect you aren't running with JMockit.   Remember that in order to run properly, you have to have "-javaagent" stuff.  Without it, those @Mocked don't work and the variable will be null.  I'm guessing that's what's happening.